# MongoDB query returns "TypeError: argument of type 'NameError' is not iterable" Error when put into a program

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Having a mongoDB collection Like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63295d64ba562f5f8842e097"),
    "device_euid" : "D8:14:40:E6:DF:5C:62:E8",
    "created_on" : ISODate("2022-09-20T06:27:48.831+0000"),
    "last_seen" : 1663841855.0.
}
```

Previously I had a function like :

```
devicesbylastseen_query = [
                {"$group": {"_id": "$last_seen", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
            ]
            last_seen_devices = execute_query(Device, devicesbylastseen_query) // execute query is simply an separate mongoDB aggregation function

            counts_dict = {'lessthan5minutes': 0, '5minutesto1hours':
                0, '1hourto1day': 0, 'greaterthan1day': 0,
                           'preapproved': 0}
            # Getting current date and time
            current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
            # Getting epoch date and times for comparisons
            cd_minus_5_min_epoch = int(round(time.mktime(
                (current_datetime - datetime.timedelta(
                    minutes=5)).timetuple())))
            cd_minus_1_hour_epoch = int(round(time.mktime(
                (current_datetime - datetime.timedelta(
                    minutes=60)).timetuple())))
            cd_minus_1_day_epoch = int(round(time.mktime(
                (current_datetime - datetime.timedelta(
                    days=1)).timetuple())))
            # Check the query result has some values
            if last_seen_devices:
                for last_seen_device in last_seen_devices:
                    if last_seen_device.get("_id").isdigit():
                        last_seen = int(last_seen_device.get("_id"))
                        # less than 5 minutes
                        if last_seen >= cd_minus_5_min_epoch:
                            counts_dict["lessthan5minutes"] = \
                                counts_dict["lessthan5minutes"] + int(
                                    last_seen_device.get("count"))
                        # 5 minutes to 1 hours
                        elif last_seen < cd_minus_5_min_epoch \
                                and last_seen >= cd_minus_1_hour_epoch:
                            counts_dict["5minutesto1hours"] = \
                                counts_dict["5minutesto1hours"] + \
                                int(last_seen_device.get("count"))
                        # 1 hour to 1 day
                        elif last_seen < cd_minus_1_hour_epoch \
                                and last_seen >= cd_minus_1_day_epoch:
                            counts_dict["1hourto1day"] = counts_dict[
                                                             "1hourto1day"] + int(
                                last_seen_device.get("count"))
                        # greater than 1 day
                        else:
                            counts_dict["greaterthan1day"] = \
                                counts_dict["greaterthan1day"] + int(
                                    last_seen_device.get("count"))
                    else:
                        counts_dict["preapproved"] = counts_dict[
                                                         "preapproved"] + int(
                            last_seen_device.get("count"))

            # Populating result, if no devices exists all counts will be zeros
            devicesbylastseen_result = {
                "lessthan5minutes": counts_dict["lessthan5minutes"],
                "5minutesto1hours": counts_dict["5minutesto1hours"],
                "1hourto1day": counts_dict["1hourto1day"],
                "greaterthan1day": counts_dict["greaterthan1day"],
                "preapproved": counts_dict["preapproved"]
            }
            return devicesbylastseen_result
```

This returns data to UI. UI displayed it as Pie chart. When we click on part of pie chart from UI, It is not clickable, it does not filter out data. For filtering I changed the query. and current function with new query:

```
    counts_dict = {'lessthan5minutes': 0, '5minutesto1hours':
                    0, '1hourto1day': 0, 'greaterthan1day': 0,
                               'preapproved': 0}
                # Getting current date and time
                current_time = int(time.time())
                # Getting epoch date and times for comparisons
                # Getting epoch date and times for comparisons
                cd_minus_5_min_epoch = current_time-300
                cd_minus_1_hour_epoch = current_time-3600
                cd_minus_1_day_epoch = current_time-86400
                # Check the query result has some values
                
                devicesbylastseen_query = [
                    {"$facet": {
                        "lessthan5minutes": [{"$match": {"last_seen": {"$gt": cd_minus_5_min_epoch, "$lt": current_time}}},
                                             {"$group": {"_id": None, "count": {"$sum": 1}}}],
                        "5minutesto1hours": [
                            {"$match": {"last_seen": {"$gt": cd_minus_1_hour_epoch, "$lt": cd_minus_5_min_epoch}}},
                            {"$group": {"_id": None, "count": {"$sum": 1}}}],
                        "1hourto1day": [
                            {"$match": {"last_seen": {"$gt": cd_minus_1_day_epoch, "$lt": cd_minus_1_hour_epoch}}},
                            {"$group": {"_id": None, "count": {"$sum": 1}}}],
                        "greaterthan1day": [{"$match": {"last_seen": {"$lt": cd_minus_1_day_epoch}}},
                                            {"$group": {"_id": None, "count": {"$sum": 1}}}],
                        "preapproved": [{"$match": {"last_seen": {"$exists": False}}},
                                        {"$group": {"_id": None, "count": {"$sum": 1}}}]
                    }
                    }
                ]
                last_seen_devices = list(execute_query(Device, devicesbylastseen_query))
                if last_seen_devices[0]:
                    for key in counts_dict:
                        if key in last_seen_devices[0].keys() and last_seen_devices[0][key]:
                            counts_dict[key] = last_seen_devices[0][key][0]["count"]
                # Populating result, if no devices exists all counts will be zeros
                devicesbylastseen_result = {
                    "lessthan5minutes": counts_dict["lessthan5minutes"],
                    "5minutesto1hours": counts_dict["5minutesto1hours"],
                    "1hourto1day": counts_dict["1hourto1day"],
                    "greaterthan1day": counts_dict["greaterthan1day"],
                    "preapproved": counts_dict["preapproved"]
                }
                return devicesbylastseen_result
```

After this query no data comes to UI. And it returns error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
TypeError: argument of type 'NameError' is not iterable
```

Comment: What is `type(last_seen_devices)`?  Does `last_seen_devices.keys()` work properly, or does it generate an error?

Comment: last_seen_devices will the the output of the devicesbylastseen_query execution, which looks like: `{
    "lessthan5minutes" : [

    ],
    "5minutesto1hours" : [

    ],
    "1hourto1day" : [

    ],
    "greaterthan1day" : [

    ],
    "preapproved" : [
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "count" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
` the .keys() method works properly.

Comment: The most recent error, `ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)` seems to indicate an error in the REST framework.  Perhaps the error is there.

Comment: REST framework is okay I think. I need to get the result from query as such so that the button in UI can be clickable. and It can get me to the data. I used $facet for that. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Isn't `last_seen_devices` an array?  If so, `last_seen_devices.keys()` won't work, will it?  Note how you iterate through `last_seen_devices` in your first code block, but don't in your second.

Comment: last_seen_devices = {
    "lessthan5minutes" : [

    ],
    "5minutesto1hours" : [

    ],
    "1hourto1day" : [

    ],
    "greaterthan1day" : [

    ],
    "preapproved" : [
        {
            "_id" : None,
            "count" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}

Comment: last_seen_devices is like this.

Comment: after iterating over it - counts_dict will be like - 
{'lessthan5minutes': 0, '5minutesto1hours': 0, '1hourto1day': 0, 'greaterthan1day': 0, 'preapproved': 1.0}........ which should be returned in api response. it should not give an error

Comment: If `last_seen_devices` is an object/dict, then the first code block wouldn't work.  In the first code block, what are you iterating with `for last_seen_device in last_seen_devices:`?

Comment: First block was working actually, I am replaced the first block query and code with second block query and code. the second one is not working.

Comment: There is no `for last_seen_device in last_seen_devices:` in the second code block.  What is `print(type(last_seen_devices))`?

Comment: Updated second block. TypeError: argument of type 'NameError' is not iterable. Basically what I'm doing is I'm having a query(devicesbylastseen_query)to aggregate. It's aggregation result in mongodb is last_seen_devices. which I'm trying to iterate over.

Comment: An _"aggregation result"_ in `pymongo` is a `command_cursor` and very similar to an iterator.  So, if your `execute_query` returns a `command_cursor`, then each `last_seen` will be a document.  What does `print(last_seen)` look like?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the second block to iterate over command_cursor object. I am converting the aggregated result to a list then I'm iterating, but with latest changes also same error is coming. P.S. I created a pymongo script locally for accessing the aggregated data the same way I'm doing in this system/product(above code). In local, it is working fine and giving result as expected, but when I put the same type of code in the system, it gives this error.

Comment: The _Traceback_ seems to indicate the error is occurring in `django`. Is `devicesbylastseen_result` in the format expected by the caller?

Comment: It is as expected by the caller.